# Draw score text in Libdgx

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I load a BitmapFont that was created out of Hiero tool. That font looks low quality and flat when drawn.

1. How do I draw a fonts like in image below with outline or shadow with HD quality.
2. How do I manage the height and width based on the screen size.
3. How do I draw (icon/text, icon/text), this mean I need to get precise width of the text in order to place the subsequent icon and text

[image]

Comment: This isn't a programming question. There are settings in Heiro for adding outlines and other effects. If it doesn't have everything you need, you can try other font-making apps like BMFont or Shoebox.

Comment: For Q2 I think you need to use Viewports. You can read about them on the API docs.

Answer (score 0):

This post answered all my questions

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Distance-field-fonts